# Convert CAML query to REST API

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I had used the below caml query in my JSOM code and I was getting 2000 items .When I tried using REST I get 99 total items.

```
camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query> <Where> <And> <Eq> <FieldRef Name='TestType' /> <Value Type='Choice'>Samples</Value> </Eq> <And> <IsNull> <FieldRef Name='TestResult' /> </IsNull> <Or> <Eq> <FieldRef Name='Tier' /> <Value Type='Text'>10</Value> </Eq> <Or> <Eq> <FieldRef Name='Tier' /> <Value Type='Text'>1</Value> </Eq> <Or> <Eq> <FieldRef Name='Tier' /><Value Type='Text'>1d</Value> </Eq> <Or> <Eq><FieldRef Name='Tier' /><Value Type='Text'>2</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Tier' /> <Value Type='Text'>5</Value> </Eq> </Or> </Or> </Or> </Or> </And> </And> </Where><OrderBy> <FieldRef Name=' Plan' Ascending='True' />  <FieldRef Name='Title' Ascending='True' /> </OrderBy> </Query>  </View>");
```

Can any one please help me in knowing what's wrong in my below rest .

```
_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('OrdersDetails')/items?$Select=Title&$filter=TestType eq Samples & TestResult eq null & Tier eq 0 or Tier eq 1 or Tier eq 1d or Tier eq 2 or Tier eq 5  & $orderby= Plan,Title asc
```

Answer (score 1):

use this `$top=4990` or `$top=4999` "Any number less than 5000" filter in your REST call

```
_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('OrdersDetails')/items?$top=4990&$Select=Title&$filter=T...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This please, think the issue in the filter query

```
_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('OrdersDetails')/items?$Select=Title&$filter=((TestType eq 'Samples') and (TestResult eq null) and (Tier eq 0 or Tier eq 1 or Tier eq 1d or Tier eq 2 or Tier eq 5))&$orderby= Plan,Title asc
```